# How to receive data in aspnet mvc from swf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionscript-3, apache-flex

This is how i send:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"));
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

request.data = { id:1, name:"hello" };

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
configureListeners(loader);
loader.load(request);
```

and this is how I receive:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(object data)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}
```

but `data` here is `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ASP method is expecting a parameter called data.  So my guess is it would work if you did this in the AS3 code:

```
request.data = { data: {id:1, name:"hello"} };  //creating an object with the property data, and giving it's value an object with id and name properties
```

Or, even better, ignore the line above and keep the flash as is, and make a View Model with `id` and `name` properties in ASP. Then the MVC data binder will do it's magic.

```
public class FlashData {
    public string id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public HttpResponseMessage Post(FlashData data){
   //data.id
   //data.name
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data);
}
```

---

Another thing you could try is this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string id, string name){
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {id=id,name=name});
}
```

Comment: The second approach did not work.. data is with properties null :(

Comment: put a break point in your ASP code and see what's actually comming in on the the Response object.  I've used an HttpResponseMessage before (only regular action methods) so I'm not sure if there is some difference there?   I'll update the answer in a moment to give you one other thing to try.

Comment: If i change to `HTTPService` object, then it works. Is there any problem of using this instead URLRequest/URLLoader?

Comment: HTTPService is specific to flex, I've never used it as I don't typically use things in the flex library.   But if it works, then great!